# Mechanical keyboard switches: linear, soft, click. What is the difference?

Tags: keyboard, user-experience

I intend to buy a keyboard with mechanical switches.
Some are available with different types of switches.

[Deck](http://www.deckkeyboards.com/) has linear and tactile.
Cherry has three different types which are sometimes referred to by their color:

- Linear = black
- Soft = brown
- Click = blue

I found enough technical information about the different types (even force-deflexion graphs), but
that doesn't really help to decide which fits me best.

As it's not easily possible to try all of them I'd like to know about your experiences.
If you have a mechanical keyboard and know what type of switches it contains, I'd like to hear your opinion.

I also would like to know which type of switches the 'Das Keyboard' uses. People seem to be happy with it so this type is probably OK.

Comment: I have a Cherry G80-3000-LSCEU-0 for about two months now. It's the one with the click pressure point (blue switches). I'm very happy with it and I consider buying one for work too.

I was quite concerned that it might be too noisy but that turned out to be no problem. It is louder than an ordinary keyboard, but really not that much.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've just ordered a Filco Majestouch and decided to go with the brown switch (described as Tactile rather than soft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that over the time, I've used all of them (keyboard switch types), and although one can feel the difference after switching from one to another, it hardly mattered in the long run. Key distribution was always more important.

I really can't see it making any difference that's worth fussing about.

The sound of the key upon pressing can be sometimes important. I'm still searching for a keyboard which will have that distintive *feel* upon pressing, while still being quiet (my home workdesk is in the bedroom, which can present problems if someone is sleeping). Same goes for the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

I have always been an enormous fan of the [IBM Model M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_M_keyboard) keyboard, pictured here:

[image: Model M]

The Model M's keys use a buckling spring mechanism.  You will be absolutely certain when you have pressed a key.

Not only do you feel it, but also you hear it.  The Model M emits a loud **click** whenever a key is pressed or released.

The Model M has removable, swappable keycaps, is dishwasher safe, and is virtually [bullet](http://cgi.ebay.com/Vintage-IBM-Model-1391401-Clicky-Keyboard-Excellent-NR_W0QQitemZ130345258269QQcmdZViewItemQQimsxZ20091117?IMSfp=TL091117186001r1043)[proof](http://digg.com/tech_news/WHAT_TO_LOOK_FOR_WHEN_PURCHASING_AN_IBM_MODEL_M_KEYBOARD?FC=PRCK0).

If you haven't tried using a Model M, then you're missing everything!

Comment: "is bulletproof" ?

Comment: Also, one intersting point ... on my late (some 10 years ago) return was a big one. Also, ibm model M. I'm now searching wikipedia, and they all have small ones ...

Comment: It's virtually bulletproof, anyhow.  It has a heavy slab of steel inside.

Comment: Well, in that case, if you don't mind - YOU hold the keyboard, and I'LL shoot ;-)